# leetcode 79 word search python solution, need help on debugging

Tags: python, algorithm, wordsearch

I'm trying to solve [leetcode 79. word search](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search/description/) with python, however, having some trouble to debug my solution. Stuck on test case: {[["A","B","C","E"],["S","F","E","S"],["A","D","E","E"]]
"ABCESEEEFS"}, it won't pass through the test case above,need some help, thanks.

```
class Solution(object):
def exist(self, board, word):
    """
    :type board: List[List[str]]
    :type word: str
    :rtype: bool
    """

    def dfs(board, word, used, x, y):
        if not word: return True

        direction = [[0, 1],[0, -1],[1, 0],[-1, 0]]

        if (0 <= x < len(board)) and (0 <= y < len(board[0])) and ((x, y) not in used) and (board[x][y] == word[0]):

            used.add((x, y))                
            return (dfs(board, word[1:], used, x + direction[0][0], y + direction[0][1]) or 
                    dfs(board, word[1:], used, x + direction[1][0], y + direction[1][1]) or 
                    dfs(board, word[1:], used, x + direction[2][0], y + direction[2][1]) or 
                    dfs(board, word[1:], used, x + direction[3][0], y + direction[3][1]))

        return False



    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[0])):
            if dfs(board, word, set(), i, j) == True: return True

    return False
```

Comment: "Need some help, thanks"? What do you need help with?

Comment: Also, your indentation is messed up, you may want to check that out.

Comment: @ connectyourcharger, I couldn't pass the test case mentioned there, something must be wrong, and I can't find it, that's the help I need

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with the code, what is the current output, and how is that different than the expected output?

Comment: @G. Anderson, I updated the question, thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that when you pass `used` into recursive `dfs`, you actually pass a reference to the function. That is, when you start at `(0,0)`, then go to `(0,1)`, and so on, you might have consumed `(1,1)` which only appears later in the sequence.

In other words, `used` will contain all board cells long before your intended search.

To fix this, create a clone of `used` and pass to recursive `dfs`:

```
for dx,dy in direction:
    used_copy = set(used)
    used_copy.add((x,y))
    if dfs(board, word[1:], used_copy, x + dx, y + dy):
        return True
return False
```

You can also remove `(x,y)` after each recursive `dfs` calls so you don't blow up your memory:

```
used.add((x,y))
for dx,dy in direction:
    if dfs(board, word[1:], used, x + dx, y + dy):
        return True

used.remove((x,y))
return False
```